# How to iterate list of dict in django template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have this dict in python django template how can i show this in select box code as value and text as name

```
{"operatingUnits":[{"code":"Banswara","name":"Banswara"},{"code":"Ratlam","name":"Ratlam"},{"code":"Mandsaur","name":"Mandsaur"},{"code":"ENUGU","name":"ENUGU"},{"code":"Bhubaneswar","name":"Dammam"},{"code":"GGN","name":"Gurgaon"},{"code":"SELANGOR","name":"SELANGOR"},{"code":"Bhiwandi","name":"Bhiwandi"},{"code":"GZB","name":"Ghaziabad"},{"code":"Gandhidham","name":"Gandhidham"},{"code":"Kota","name":"Kota"},{"code":"Udaipur","name":"Udaipur"},{"code":"Neemuch","name":"Neemuch"},{"code":"Jodhpur","name":"Jodhpur"},{"code":"KEDAH","name":"KEDAH"},{"code":"ANTARA","name":"ANTARA"},{"code":"ABUJA","name":"Pune"},{"code":"NASHIK","name":"nashik"},{"code":"Ind","name":"Indore"},{"code":"CHENNAI","name":"CHENNAI"},{"code":"RIYADHFRANCHISEE","name":"Chandigarh"},{"code":"123","name":"dsd"},{"code":"HARIDWAR","name":"HARIDWAR"},{"code":"PUNE","name":"Jeddah"},{"code":"VAPI","name":"vapi"},{"code":"Delhi","name":"HO Delhi"},{"code":"HYDERABAD","name":"HYDERABAD"},{"code":"ISTANBUL","name":"ISTANBUL"},{"code":"Kolkata","name":"Kolkata"},{"code":"Ahmadabad","name":"Ibadan"}]}
```

I am facing problem in django template

I want select

after run a loop on this i want this one and this loop i want to write down in a templage

```
<Select >
   <option value="code" > name</select>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django you can perform all sorts of lookups (see [Variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables) in the documentation) using only the `.` operator. You need to first loop over the list and then access each value using it's key in the loop:

```
<select>
    {% for operating_unit in operatingUnits %}
        <option value="{{ operating_unit.code }}">{{ operating_unit.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: it this will work then why did you i ask this question here

Comment: @Pythonlogix what are you talking about? It is you who have asked the question... Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I have change in my question

Comment: I am sure my answer does that itself... Can you show how you are passing this list into the context?

Comment: I have already tried this one not working

Comment: yes this one is working in core but not in django templates

Comment: @Pythonlogix please add relevant parts of your view to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229376/discussion-between-python-logix-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).